# Meaning of "make trim of"

Tags: archaicisms

In the [Life of Flavius Josephus](http://gutenberg.org/ebooks/2846), as translated by Whiston in the 18th century, Josephus says:

> Moreover, when I was a child, and about fourteen years of age, I was
> commended by all for the love I had to learning; on which account the
> high priests and principal men of the city came then frequently to me
> together, in order to know my opinion about the accurate understanding
> of points of the law. And when I was about sixteen years old, I had a
> mind to make trim of the several sects that were among us.

What does "make trim of" mean? Try on for size? Evaluate?

Comment: The word "trim" is a typographical or OCR error. The actual word in the translated text is "trial." See [this 1854 edition of William Whiston's translation of _The Works of Flavius Josephus_](https://books.google.com/books?id=TBA4AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA129&dq=%22And+when+I+was+about+sixteen+years+old,+I+had+a+mind%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_9pGI1OLuAhUgCjQIHcJdAysQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22And%20when%20I%20was%20about%20sixteen%20years%20old%2C%20I%20had%20a%20mind%22&f=false).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a typographical or OCR error in a text, rather than on a real-world issue of English language or usage.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the following self-answer is correct, but here's what I found out.

The [original Greek](https://archive.org/details/L186JosephusILifeAgainstApion/page/n27/mode/2up) is this:

> γενομενος εβουληθην των παρ ημιν αἱρέσεων ἐμπειρίαν λαβειν

My Greek is pretty poor, but I think γίγνομαι=to become, and βούλομαι=to wish, ἐμπειρία=experience, practice. Maybe [αἱρέσεων](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%B1%E1%BC%B1%CF%81%CE%AD%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%B1) is some other koine usage of a word that has to do with import duties. So anyway, it seems like he wants to become experienced. The translation by Thackeray on the right-hand side across from the Greek is "gain personal experience," which seems to match this word-by-word translation.

So it seems like the idea that Whiston is trying to represent in English with "make trim of" is something that means "gain personal experience." If it's a reference to tailoring, then it probably does mean "try on for size."

Comment: Henry St. John Thackeray agrees with you, translating this passage: "At about the age of sixteen I determined to gain personal experience of the several sects into which our nation is divided." https://archive.org/details/L186JosephusILifeAgainstApion/page/n27/mode/2up